# Help me understand the mechanics involved in performing a wheelie

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, experimental-physics

I am a mechanical engineering student trying to understand the mechanics of a wheelie (a maneuver).

Can someone explain to me the mechanics behind performing a wheelie? With a free-body diagram. And how the system is stable throughout the performing wheelie. When the biker balances the bike on one wheel. And how the change in the center of mass affects the system

I am trying to understand. the dynamic FBD of lifting the wheelie, and the relatively static FBD of maintaining the wheelie once it is up

[image]

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpKltBb2n1M

Comment: Why don't you start by showing what you have considered so far...

Comment: model force against the ground versus the center of mass of the bike.  if the torque due to acceleration is greater than the torque (vs rear wheel) due to center of gravity, bike will wheelie.

Comment: This sounds very homework-ish.  Please describe what you've done so far to solve the problem.  You may want to start with a free-body diagram of a bike under acceleration but with both wheels on the ground.  Compute the downward force on the front wheel as a function of acceleration.

Comment: I'd imagine it would be very similar to the mechanics for a unicycle.

Comment: Show what you have done so far, like your attempt at the free body diagram.

Comment: This is a physics question, not an engineering question.

Comment: i am looking to understand the dynamic FBD of lifting the wheelie, and the relatively static FBD of maintaining the wheelie once it is up

Comment: I've merged your two accounts (I noticed the edit was made from an unregistered account with the same email associated with it), and merged your duplicate question into this one as well (since your closed duplicate question had an answer and this one didn't).

Answer (score 0):

[image: bike diagram]

Among many forces and reactions, we isolate only the two moments that are basically involved in the uplifting of the front wheel.

The overturning moment which is the weight of the bike and rider times the X, the distance of CG of the bike to the rear tire ground contact point. And the acceleration of the bike transmitted by the wheel times H, the distance of the CG to the ground. As soon as

$$m\alpha * H> mg*x$$
The front wheel uplifts.

Then the rider needs to immediately throttle down and stabilize the bike by holding the contact point of the rear wheel directly under the CG of the bike.

Comment: thanks for your help.
can you explain the dynamic FBD of lifting the wheelie, and the relatively static FBD of maintaining the wheelie once it is up