# explain me the dynamics involved in performing wheelie

Tags: applied-mechanics

Wheelie is a motorbike stunt in which the rider balances the bike on one wheel.
I am trying to understand the dynamics of performing this wheelie. with a free-body diagram
and all the forces acting on the system

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/55676/10902

Comment: You asked this question 2 days ago. Do not ask the same question twice. It will be closed as a duplicate. Just because you asked a question does not guarantee you will receive an answer.